# Is there a female Predator?

Tags: predator, predator-series

In all the movies featuring the [**Predator** creatures](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predator_(alien)) or Yautja we can only see what appear to be male **Predators**. I am wondering if **a female Predator** exists, and if there is any information about them?

Comment: How do we even know if the Predator has a gender?

Comment: Rule 63: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=rule%2063

Comment: @JimmyShelter : Rule 34 http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=rule%2034

Comment: The original Predator was female. After selecting Arnie but then being rejected sexually by him, she could no longer go on living, hence the suicide bomb. Though she spitefully tried to kill him, what she really wanted was for him to return and profess his love...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In the film canon, there's no mention of gender. In fact, there's no mention of whether the Predators even *have* gender.

In the [book and comic series,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliens_vs._Predator_%28novel_series%29) there are extensive mentions of Predator females (bordering on slashfic in some cases) who seem largely to remain on the planet and raise little baby Predators despite their greater-than-average intelligence.

From [*AVP: Prey*](https://avp.wikia.com/wiki/Aliens_vs._Predator:_Prey);

> *"A warrior who would dare such would not be wise, for an insulted and angry yautja female was not something even a not-too-wise male wanted
>   to create. Assuming the warrior was armed and expert, it might almost
>   be an even match, but Dachande would put his wager on the female. His
>   most recent partner had tossed him across a room during the heat of
>   their mating and that had been an accident..."*

and

> *"Yautja females were bigger than males; it was apparently the reverse
>   for oomans."*

and

> *..."It also explained why this warrior was smarter than most of the yautja he taught. Females of any species were usually smarter than the
>   males."*

Comment: "despite their greater-than-average intelligence" - I think that they choose not to go and fight xenomorphs *because* of their greater-than-average-intelligence.

Comment: or maybe xenomorph hunts are just bachelor parties?

Answer (score 6):

In [*Predator: Forever Midnight*](https://www.darkhorse.com/Books/10-772/Predator-Forever-Midnight-Novel) (which I don't think is canon, but still worthwhile as an answer here) the Predators are not as we know them in canon (i.e., the Yautja) they are called the Hish-qu-Ten.

These Predators are hermaphroditic and can switch between genders regularly. The female phase have exactly six offspring and can be told apart from the male variants through their flesh braids.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few notable Female Yautja (that are actually named characters) in the books and graphic novels:

- Big Mama - From the comic *AvP: Deadliest of the Species*. A big Predator with no female features (breasts) and no special armor/costume. She is actually quite badass and survives the hunt.
- Sister Midnight - from the *Witchblade/Aliens/Darkness/Predator:
  Mindhunter* crossover comic. Looks feminine, has breasts and has a dress like costume. Has a special relationship with Witchblade, fights some Aliens, detonates her self-destruct and dies.
- Vagouti - From the *Predator: If It Bleeds* novel story "Rematch" (the story is a sequel to the book *Predator: Turnabout*). There is not much physical description on her but she is hunting together with her mate. They are both killed by humans.

There is also Machiko Noguchi, who is a human female who joined the Predators (she is often mistaken for a female Predator).
There is more information and pictures about them [here](https://www.avpcentral.com/female-yautja).